# "start python" does not work in MS powershell for windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell, windows-7

Until yesterday I used to be perfectly able to run python scripts in python like so -

**start python  [python_script_name]**

However by now, (in this span of time, I have installed GitHub, gotten stuck in booting Windows 7 and forced to use Windows Restore which removed GitHub and now Windows 7 boots) I can only use

**start python.exe [python_script_name]**

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

[Python version - 2.7.5
Windows 7 Home]

Answer (score 1):

`start` is a command built into `cmd.exe`, not PowerShell.exe. In PowerShell, `start` is a default alias for the `Start-Process` cmdlet, which operates differently than the `start` command in cmd.exe.

In PowerShell, you'll want to use a command like:

```
Start-Process -FilePath c:\path\to\python.exe -ArgumentList 'c:\path\to\script.ps1' -Wait -NoNewWindow;
```

Comment: you probably meant ...\script.py?

Comment: Yeah, or that. Whoopsie :)